# Do we have $R\simeq S$ for two submodules $R,S$ of $A^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules, module-isomorphism

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. Given two submodules $R,S$ of $A^n$ (where $n\in\Bbb N$), if there exists an isomorphism of $A$-modules $A^n/R\simeq A^n/S$, then do we have $R\simeq S$?

Note that this is definitely false for quotients of non-free modules: see, e.g., [Quotient modules isomorphic $ \Rightarrow$ submodules isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798119/quotient-modules-isomorphic-rightarrow-submodules-isomorphic) or [Isomorphy of quotient modules implies isomorphy of submodules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95899/isomorphy-of-quotient-modules-implies-isomorphy-of-submodules) .

Answer (score 1):

This is false even for direct summands. For example, take $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2=1)$, the co-ordinate ring of the real sphere. Let $P$ be defined as the kernel of the surjective map $R^3\to R$ given by $(x,y,z)$. ($P$ is the tangent bundle of the sphere). Then $P\oplus R\cong R^3$, but $P$ is not free.

Comment: And with proofs: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/stablyfree.pdf

Answer (score -3):

No.

Let $A=\Bbb Z^\Bbb N=\{\,f\colon \Bbb N\to\Bbb Z\,\}$, $n=1$, $R=\Bbb Z=\{\,f\in A\mid \forall n>0\colon f(n)=0\,\}$, and $S=0$. Then $A^1/R\cong A^1/S\cong A$, but of coure $R\not\cong S$.

Comment: These are not isomorphic as $A$-modules. Note that $\mathrm{Ann}(A/R)=R$ while $\mathrm{Ann}(A/S)=S$. But, annihilators of isomorphic modules coincide.